# asynchronously submit values to controller? yii2

Tags: php, validation, yii2, rules, scenarios

So here's the deal. The ActiveForm below is supposed to receive two variables: $tt (radio) and $value (string numeric input) and send them to controller.

$value needs to be validated based on different rules and scenarios, which are defined in InputField model. $tt is radio value, so I'm not defining rules for it as of now.

The trick is, I'd like there to be some sort of input validation for $value, and the rules for it should change depending on what the user set as his $tt value. With this kind of configuration, controller never receives neither $tt, nor $value, I think the reason is conflicting rules for it.

Ideally, I would like my view to send checked radio $tt value (with jQuery or smthng) to controller, and for controller then to set scenario for the model so it has proper validation rules set up, which input field for $value in the view will operate on.

Yii2 experts: 1) can you explain me why my controller fails to receive any value. 2)suggest anything for what I was planning to do?

`

//View fragment

```
       $valueForm = ActiveForm::begin([ 
              'id' => 'input-field', 
          'action' => ['value-search/index'], 
          'method' => 'post', 
         'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal'] ]); ?>

<?= $valueForm->field($valueModel, 'tt')
              ->radioList(['P_sat'=>'Sat. Pressure', 'T_sat'=>'Sat. Temperature'])
              ->label('Select table type'); ?> 
<?= $valueForm->field($valueModel, 'value')
              ->textInput(['options' => ['type'=>'number', 'name'=>'value','id'=>'value']]); ?> 
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

---

//Model

```
class InputField extends \yii\base\Model
```

{

```
const SCENARIO_PSAT = 'P_sat';
const SCENARIO_TSAT = 'T_sat';
public $tt;
public $value;


public function scenarios() {
    return [
        self::SCENARIO_PSAT => ['tt','value'],
        self::SCENARIO_TSAT => ['tt','value'],
    ];
}

public function rules() {
    return [
        ['tt','safe'],
        ['value', 'double', 'numberPattern' => '/[0-9]+?(\.[0-9]{0,5})?/', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 22064, 
        'on' => self::SCENARIO_PSAT],
        ['value', 'double', 'numberPattern' => '/[0-9]+?(\.[0-9]{0,5})?/', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 373.95, 
        'on' => self::SCENARIO_TSAT],
    ];
}
```

//Operating action from the controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{   
    $inputModel = new InputField;

    $inputModel->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());

    $tt = $inputModel->tt;


    switch($tt) {
        case 'P_sat': $inputModel->scenario = $inputModel::SCENARIO_PSAT;
                     break;
        case 'T_sat': $inputModel->scenario = $inputModel::SCENARIO_TSAT;
                     break;
        default: throw new UserException('setTableType is not returning shit');
    }


    if ($inputModel->validate('value')) { 
        $searchValue = $inputModel->value;
        $this->test = $inputModel->tt;
        $this->test2 = $inputModel->value;

    }  else {
        throw new UserException('Input is not validated');
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        //'provider' => $provider,
        'array' => $this->test,
        'array2' => $this->test2
    ]);
}
```

`

Both test and test2, which are supposed to receive $tt and $value from the model, are NULL :(

Comment: Where is submit button? Why you didn't use client side validation?  [Check examples](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#creating-validators)

Comment: I wasn't using submit button a the time :/. Instead, I was using enter to submit values. But for some reason, something was preventing server side validation by validate(). Then, I removed scenarios and just used "when keyword" to run the specific rules. But validate() still wasn't working, so i had to create a separate function to validate data on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario has to be set before loading a value

```
public function actionIndex()
{   
    $inputModel = new InputField;

    $inputModel->load(\Yii::$app->request->post());

    $tt = $inputModel->tt;


    switch($tt) {
        case 'P_sat': $inputModel->scenario = $inputModel::SCENARIO_PSAT;
                 break;
        case 'T_sat': $inputModel->scenario = $inputModel::SCENARIO_TSAT;
                 break;
        default: throw new UserException('setTableType is not returning shit');
    }


    if ($inputModel->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $inputModel->validate('value')) { 
        $searchValue = $inputModel->value;
        $this->test = $inputModel->tt;
        $this->test2 = $inputModel->value;

    }  else {
        throw new UserException('Input is not validated');
    }

    return $this->render('index', [
        //'provider' => $provider,
        'array' => $this->test,
        'array2' => $this->test2
    ]);
}
```